# How to generate HTML from a lcov file on Windows via WSL?

Tags: flutter, code-coverage, lcov

I am using Flutter to generate the lcov file and now I want to use WSL to generate the HTML file for reading the data. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, after generating the `lcov.info` files on windows you must replace all `\` characters for `/` because linux can't understand the backslashes.

Then you can simply invoke the linux command for lcov generation through any windows terminal via:

```
wsl genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/output/
```

- You invoke this command inside the project you are working on.
- The first parameter `coverage/lcov.info` is the path for the lcov file.
- The second parameter `-o coverage/output/` is the output folder where the html files will be placed.